# Windows上でGPU処理を検討する際の実装方針及び見積もりにつきまして

Tags: windows, gpu, opengl, directx

Windows上でクロマキー処理やαブレンディングの処理を行った上で4K,60Pで出力を行いたいと思っています。
そこで、それらをGPUで実装する上で下記の3点についてアドバイスいただきたいです。

1) DirectXとOpenGLのメリット・デメリットについて
クロマキー処理やαブレンディング処理を行うことを調べていると、DirectXやOpenGLを使う情報を見るのですが、
それらのメリット・デメリットはどのような点にありますでしょうか？
OpenGLは、マルチプラットフォームがメリットのような記載も見かけるのですが、
Direct XがLinuxに移植されるような記事もあり、現状のメリットとデメリットについて教えていただければと思っています。

「WSL 2」に「DirectX」が追加 ～将来的にはLinux GUIアプリへの対応も
https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1253524.html

2) 必要なGPUの見積もりについて
やりたいこととしては、2次元のクロマキー処理やαブレンディングのみなので、GPUの処理負荷はそこまで高くないのでは
と考えているのですが、このような場合の見積もりはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

3) DirectXのバージョンにつきまして
DirectXにはバージョンがいろいろありDirectX 11.3/11.4はDirectX 12と並行してアップデートが継続されているようなのですが、3D処理を行わないαブレンディング処理の場合、どのバージョンを使用するのが良いのでしょうか？

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_DirectX
一方で、従来の手厚い高レベルレイヤーであるDirectX 11にも、DirectX 12で導入された新機能の一部が盛り込まれる形で、DirectX 11.3/11.4のようにDirectX 12と平行してアップデートが継続されている。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

根本的な認識が違うと思います。

> やりたいこととしては、2次元のクロマキー処理やαブレンディングのみ

と言うことはありえなくて、処理対象の映像についての検討が漏れています。

> 4K,60Pで出力で行いたい

ということは静止画ですらなく、連続する映像、動画などではありませんか？ その処理の方が重要です。圧縮されていればデコード処理が必要ですし、無圧縮なら膨大なデータ量を安定的に処理する必要があります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

データの入力に関しては、Live Gamer 4Kという4K HDRに対応したソフトウェアエンコード方式のキャプチャーボードを使用する予定です。

キャプチャーボード Live Gamer 4K(GC573)とLive Gamer ULTRA(GC553)レビュー
https://www.pc-koubou.jp/magazine/9450

それなので、デコード処理は不要ではないかと思っています。

また、GPU処理後の映像についても、出力するだけで保存することもないのでエンコードもなしで大丈夫ではないかと考えております。

Comment: @uraxurax 誰がキャプチャボードの出力データをGPUに入力するのでしょうか？

Comment: キャプチャーボードからのデータの取得は、DirectShowを使えばキャプチャできると考えています。
https://interaction-lab.org/kawashima/firewire/directshow.html#vidcap

プログラムからGPUを使って処理する部分については、DirectXもしくはopenGLを使う認識でいます。