# YUVのデータをWindowsで表示する方法につきまして

Tags: windows, opencv, opengl, directx, openframeworks

下記のGiGEカメラから取得した映像(4504×4504, 60fps, YUV422)をWindows10上で低遅延で描画したいと考えています。

https://www.argocorp.com/cam/25GigE/EVT/HB-20000-SB.html

解像度が4504×4504,フレームレートが60fpsなので処理負荷が高くならないか心配しているのですが、WindowsのどのAPIを使用するのが良いかアドバイスをいただけますでしょうか？

軽く調べただけでもいろいろならAPIやライブラリが出てくるのですが、上記の目的を達成する為に
適切なライブラリがどれであるかアドバイスいただけたらと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

- DirectDraw
- DirectShow
- OpenCV
- OpenGL
- Openframeworks

Comment: [クロマキー処理やαブレンディングよりも映像そのものの処理の方が重要](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/67014/4236)という指摘を理解いただけたということでしょうか？ そうであれば先の質問を解決済みとしていただけたらと思います。

Comment: 参照先に「ビューワソフトeCapture、eSDKを無償添付」とありますが、そこに何か仕様が記載されているか、サンプルプログラム等があるのでは？ 実態はこちらのようですが。[Software SDK](https://emergentvisiontec.com/resources/?tab=ss)

Comment: 産業用カメラとのことですから、まずはキャプチャ部(eSDK)のソフトウェア仕様とサンプルプログラム等を確認されたほうが良いと思います。おそらくDirectX(Draw or Show) か OpenGL のいずれかと予想しますが。

Comment: 少し気になったのは解像度4504×4504はセンサ[Sony CMOS S IMX531](https://www.sony-semicon.co.jp/products/common/pdf/IMX531-AAMJ_AAQJ_Flyer.pdf)画素のようですから、実際にあなたが処理したいのがモノクロ／RGBカラー／RAWデータのいずれかも併せて確認されたほうがよいのでは？

Comment: @kunif さん
アドバイスありがとうございます。

Software SDKにサンプルプログラムはあったものですが、プログラムの実装がデータを取得するところまでで描画は行っていませんでした。

Comment: @yohjp さん
いろいろとアドバイスありがとうございます。
サンプルプログラムはあったものですが、プログラムの実装がデータを取得するところまでで描画は行っていませんでした。
また、取得できるフォーマットは"RGB8, BGR8, YUV411, YUV422, YUV444"なのですが、60fpsで動作させる為にYUV422で動作させようとしております。
https://emergentvisiontec.com/products/area-scan-cameras/25-gige-area-scan-cameras-hb-series/hb-20000-sb/

Comment: @sayuri さん ご指摘ありがとうございます。先ほど解決済にさせていただきました。いろいろとフォローいただきありがとうございます。

Comment: YUV422にも色々 [YUVフォーマット及び YUV<->RGB変換](https://interaction-lab.org/kawashima/firewire/yuv.html), [YUV pixel formats](https://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php) あるようですが、OpenCVなら[cvtColor()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) とか自前ならこの辺が参考になるかも [YUV to RGB...](https://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php), [How to convert RGB -> YUV -> RGB...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17892346/9014308), [Correct YUV422 to RGB...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8042563/9014308), [Converting YUV into BGR or...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7954416/9014308)

Comment: こんなのを見つけたので参考になるかも。[Home Browse Graphics Graphics Viewers YUV Player](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raw-yuvplayer/), [Tee0125/yuvplayer](https://github.com/Tee0125/yuvplayer), [\[UtVideo\] バージョン 14.0.0](http://umezawa.dyndns.info/wordpress/?p=4723)

Comment: @kunif さん
有用な情報ありがとうございます。
参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リストにないもので[Media Foundation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk)という選択肢もあります。これはDirectShowの後継で、Windows Media Playerのメディア制御部分を独立させたものとなります。[Media Sourceを実装](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/writing-a-custom-media-source)すればあとは[Video Playback](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/how-to-play-unprotected-media-files)できるようになるかな、とか。
（デバイスドライバがビデオキャプチャデバイスを実現してくれていれば、Media Sourceも自動的に用意されるんですが、その辺りはよくわかりません）

Comment: いつも有用な情報ありがとうございます。
参考にさせていただきます。